# python ctypes wlapi no interfaces

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm playing around with the windows api in python, now I'm trying to list the Wlan interfaces with the WlanEnumInterfaces function.
This is my code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes


#Api Enums
(wlan_interface_state_not_ready,wlan_interface_state_connected,wlan_interface_state_ad_hoc_network_formed,wlan_interface_state_disconnecting,wlan_interface_state_disconnected,wlan_interface_state_associating,wlan_interface_state_discovering,wlan_interface_state_authenticating) = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

#ApiFunctions
WlanOpenHandle = ctypes.windll.wlanapi.WlanOpenHandle
WlanEnumInterfaces = ctypes.windll.wlanapi.WlanEnumInterfaces

#ApiStructs
class GUID(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Data1', wintypes.DWORD),('Data2', wintypes.WORD),('Data3', wintypes.WORD),('Data4', wintypes.BYTE * 8)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("InterfaceGuid",GUID),("strInterfaceDescription",wintypes.WCHAR),("isState",ctypes.c_int)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dwNumberOfItems",wintypes.DWORD),("dwIndex",wintypes.DWORD),("InterfaceInfo",ctypes.POINTER(WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO))]


def get_wlan_interfaces(client_handle):
    interfaces = WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST()
    WlanEnumInterfaces(client_handle,None,ctypes.pointer(interfaces))
    return interfaces

def get_client_handle():
    client_version = ctypes.c_ulong(1)
    wlan_api_version = ctypes.c_ulong()
    client_handle = ctypes.c_ulong()
    WlanOpenHandle(client_version,0,wlan_api_version,client_handle)
    return client_handle

handle = get_client_handle()
interfaces = get_wlan_interfaces(handle)
print interfaces.dwNumberOfItems
```

So it should print the count of the interfaces, but it only print "0".
There should at least be one interface.
Can someone find  the problem?

Now I changed my code to the following one:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes


#Api Enums
(wlan_interface_state_not_ready,wlan_interface_state_connected,wlan_interface_state_ad_hoc_network_formed,wlan_interface_state_disconnecting,wlan_interface_state_disconnected,wlan_interface_state_associating,wlan_interface_state_discovering,wlan_interface_state_authenticating) = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

#ApiFunctions
WlanOpenHandle = ctypes.windll.wlanapi.WlanOpenHandle
WlanEnumInterfaces = ctypes.windll.wlanapi.WlanEnumInterfaces

#ApiStructs
class GUID(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Data1', wintypes.DWORD),('Data2', wintypes.WORD),('Data3', wintypes.WORD),('Data4', wintypes.BYTE * 8)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("InterfaceGuid",GUID),("strInterfaceDescription",wintypes.WCHAR),("isState",ctypes.c_int)]

class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(wintypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dwNumberOfItems",wintypes.DWORD),("dwIndex",wintypes.DWORD),("InterfaceInfo",ctypes.POINTER((WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO))]


def get_wlan_interfaces(client_handle):
    interfaces = WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST()
    WlanEnumInterfaces(client_handle,None,ctypes.pointer(interfaces))
    return interfaces

def get_client_handle():
    client_version = wintypes.DWORD(1)
    wlan_api_version = wintypes.DWORD()
    client_handle = wintypes.HANDLE()
    print WlanOpenHandle(client_version,None,ctypes.pointer(wlan_api_version),ctypes.pointer(client_handle))
    return client_handle

handle = get_client_handle()
interfaces = get_wlan_interfaces(handle)
print interfaces.dwNumberOfItems
```

Now I don't recive an error code but I recive an always changing count of interfaces.

Comment: You should check what the functions are returning, there may be an error. E.g. `err = WlanEnumInterfaces(client_handle,None,ctypes.pointer(interfaces))`.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look on it

Comment: I recive the error code ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER for WlanOpenHandle

Comment: For that function it looks like `pReserved` needs to be null (`None`) and you possibly need to know the correct value for `phClientHandle` as well. According to the docs that can be found "using the macro `WLAN_API_MAKE_VERSION(_major, _minor)`".